# the case of separating N disjoint convex cones

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-cone

I am learing about the separation theorem :

separation between a (closed) convex set $X$ in $\mathbb R^n$ and a vector outside $X$.

I know about it but what are some examples where separation is used to prove other theorems relevant for optimization.

And what is the case of separating N disjoint convex cones.(theorem statement)
Any links where i can get it.

Comment: What is your **question**? What I the **exact statement** of your problem? Make your post **concise** because, as it stands now, your post needs details or clarity.

Comment: My question is what are the  examples where separation is used to prove other theorems relevant for optimization.

And what is  the case (theorem statement) of separating N disjoint convex cones . @Invisible

Answer (score 1):

To give you an example where they appear in optimization: Duality Theory is a concept which is  based on separation arguments. For example the *Fenchel-Moreau theorem* uses separation arguments and is used to derive other theorems concerning Conjugate duality.
Also algorithms like the *Alternating Direction Method of Multipliers* or the *Primal-Dual Hybrid Gradient Method* are therefore based on separation arguments. You should be able to find reference online, as these concepts are quite common.

Comment: yes i search for it and i found : slater’s condition , farkas lemma and some others but i am not sure on it so. @donpartini